# Why does the hanleOpen and handleClose doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, toggle

I have a React component called FlightAuto that includes a dropdown menu. The dropdown menu should open when the user focuses on an input field and close when the user clicks outside the menu. However, the handleOpen and handleClose functions I've implemented don't seem to be working as expected.

Here is the code for the FlightAuto component:

```
// Imports omitted for brevity

const FlightAuto = (props) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  // Other state and function declarations omitted for brevity

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  // Other code omitted for brevity

  return (
    <div className="searchMenu-loc px-24 lg:py-20 lg:px-0 js-form-dd js-liverSearch">
      <div
        data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
        data-bs-auto-close="true"
        data-bs-offset="0,22"
      >
        <!-- Input field and other elements omitted for brevity -->
      </div>

      {open && (
        <div className="shadow-2 dropdown-menu min-width-400">
          <!-- Dropdown menu options omitted for brevity -->
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default FlightAuto;
```

I have tried using the handleOpen and handleClose functions as event handlers for the input field's onFocus and onBlur events, respectively. However, when I focus on the input field, the dropdown menu doesn't open, and it also doesn't close when I click outside the menu.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and I would appreciate any insights or suggestions to fix this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!

When trying to implement the handleOpen and handleClose functions in the FlightAuto component, I expected the dropdown menu to open when the user focuses on the input field and close when the user clicks outside the menu.

To achieve this, I used the onFocus event on the input field to call the handleOpen function and the onBlur event to call the handleClose function. Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
<input
  autoComplete="off"
  type="search"
  placeholder="Where are you going?"
  className="js-search js-dd-focus"
  value={search}
  onChange={handleSearchChange}
  onFocus={handleOpen}
  onBlur={handleClose}
/>
```

I expected that when I focused on the input field, the handleOpen function would be called and set the open state to true, causing the dropdown menu to be displayed. Similarly, when I clicked outside the menu, I expected the handleClose function to be called and set the open state to false, hiding the dropdown menu.

However, despite implementing these functions, the dropdown menu doesn't open when I focus on the input field, and it doesn't close when I click outside the menu.

I have reviewed the code and ensured that the event handlers are correctly assigned to the input field. I have also checked for any potential conflicts or issues with other parts of the component. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to identify the cause of this problem.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you create sandbox and replicate the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works perfectly fine for me. Check for some CSS errors

Comment: This should be comment instead of answer.

Comment: Yes it works now it was sommething from my parent component.